# I cannot get the right query in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, orm

I got a statement to get a record in Laravel. However, it has the exception

```
Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'isok_toteacher' in 'where clause'

$lessonDetail = Lesson::join('lesson','lesson_en.id_lesson','=','lesson.id')
                ->with('theme_id.theme_name.lesson_name.next_lesson')
                ->with(array('notes' => function($query){
                    $query->where('isok_toteacher','1');
                }))->remember(\Config::get('cache.redis_long'))->find($lessonId);
```

And I print out the query, it becomes

```
select * from `teacher_notes` where `teacher_notes`.`id_teacher` = 13401 and `teacher_notes`.`id_lesson` in (27) and `isok_toteacher` = 1
```

I am not so sure why the `with(array('notes' => function($query)` is not pointing to notes table instead it points to teacher_notes and finally make the column unavailable.

Comment: Do you want to only filter on the `isok_toteach`? or do you also want to include the whole `notes` in the result? If you only want to filter with it, you can use `whereHas` instead of with

Comment: Thanks Teun. Is that any reason that caused the 'notes' table subsituted by 'teacher_notes'?

Comment: Honestly, I don't know. Looking at the query, I would have expected it to add the `notes`, but only the `notes` where `isok_toteacher` is `1`.

Comment: Can you please explain what are you trying to get? And the structure of the related tables?

Comment: You must provide _isok_toteach_ in which tables? EX: _lesson.isok_toteach_